# Why is $A^{m} - 1 = (A^{m'} - 1)(A^{m'(a-1)} + A^{m'(a-2)} + ... + A^{m'} + 1).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Show that if $m$ is a multiple of $a^n$, then $(a + 1)^m -1$ is a multiple of $a^{n+1}$.

Here is a solution, but I don't understand it:
We use induction on $n$. For $n = 0$ we have to show that $(a+1)^m - 1$ is a multiple of $a$. That is obvious if we expand by the binomial theorem. So suppose it is true for $n$. Put $m = am'$, where $m'$ is divisible by $a^n$. For convenience we also put $A = a+1$. **Then we have (How is this obtained?)** $$A^{m} - 1 = (A^{m'} - 1)(A^{m'(a-1)} + A^{m'(a-2)} + ... + A^{m'} + 1).$$ The first bracket is divisible by $a^{n+1}$ by induction. The second bracket has $a$ terms, so adding $a$ and subtracting $a$ $1$'s we can write it as $$a + (A^{m'(a-1)} - 1) + (A^{m'(a-2)} - 1) + ... + (A^{m'} - 1).$$ Now each term is divisible by $a$ and hence the sum is divisible by $a$. So $A^m - 1$ is divisible by $a^{n+2}$ as required.

Comment: Is it $A^{m'(a-1)}$ instead of $A^{m'}(a-1)$ and so on...?

Comment: http://www.math-olympiad.com/36th-eotvos-competition-1932-problems-solutions.htm Not here.

Comment: After reading the solution I am sure that the answer to my above question is yes. Also it must be $a^{n+1}$ instead of $a^n+1$.

Comment: So you saying that there is a mistake in the given link?

Comment: As written this proof states that $A^{m'}(a-1) - 1=(a+1)^{m'}(a-1) - 1$ is divisible by $a$, which is not true.

Comment: Ok. But then I have another question: why is $(a+1)^{m'(a-1)}$ divisible by $a$?

Comment: @user64985: it is not. Not until you subtract $1$. By the binomial expansion argument once again.